# Pausing a Android countdowntimer with same button

Tags: android, countdowntimer

I have found numerous examples of how to pause a countdowntimer in Android, but each of these examples utilises more than 1 button (pause, resume and cancel).

I want to have one button that when I press it the timer starts, then when I press it again it pauses (cancelling the original timer, capturing the timer value) and resumes when clicked again (taking the captured time from the pause to start off a new counterdowntimer).

Does anyone have an example of how to achieve this? I have tried if else loops in the onClick listener of the button. I have a very crude semi-working example;

```
if (gameOn == 1) {
 if((clkOnTimerBtn % 2)==0) {
    isPaused = true; // PAUSE COUNTDOWN TIMER
    resumeCountDownTimer(view, "pause");
 } else { // RESUME COUNTDOWN TIMER
   resumeCountDownTimer(view, "resume");
}
```

The problem with the above is that this is carried out in the button onclick listener, so if a new CountDownTimer is created inside my resumeCountDownTimer its not possible to access the timer later on to cancel it (pause). I have also tried looking for a way to cancel all countdowntimers, messy if I could, but I couldn't find any examples or references to doing so as this would at least get the desired behaviour even if it isn't the most elegant way.

Comment: Have  you tried to put a click counter. For example when timer starts, increment, then when you click again, you have an if statements that will pause and increment, and when you press again, it will stop the timer and reset the counter to zero again

Comment: @YunusKulyyev thats exactly what I've tried :), the clkOnTimerBtn increments every time the onClick for the button is triggered. That part works great, but I've put the new timer in the resumeCountDownTimer method, and once its triggered I lose the focus to cancel it :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understood you correctly, something like this should work.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

CountDownTimer countDownTimer;
long duration = 100000; //This is the initial time,
long millisecondsLeft = 100000; // This is the time left. At the start it equales the duration.
boolean isCountDownTimerActive = false;
Button startButton;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


    start = (Button) findViewById(R.id.startStop);
    final TextView timeLeft = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.timeLeft);

    start.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            if (isCountDownTimerActive) {
                if (countDownTimer != null)
                    countDownTimer.cancel();
                isCountDownTimerActive = false;
            } else {
                countDownTimer = new CountDownTimer(millisecondsLeft, 1000) {
                    @Override
                    public void onTick(long l) {
                        millisecondsLeft = l;
                        timeLeft.setText(" " + l);
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onFinish() {

                    }
                };
                isCountDownTimerActive = true;
                countDownTimer.start();
            }
        }
    });
}
```

}